# Boostrap modal formatting for rwd

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On my current site (www.webuyfitprojects.com) I am implementing a bootstrap modal ('launch demo modal' button is near the bottom).

I added this code to remove the html margin shifting issue when the modal is opened.  (there are multiple threads about it on here):

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').bind('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $("html").css("margin-right", "0px");
    });
    $('#myModal').bind('show.bs.modal', function () {
      $("html").css("margin-right", "-15px");
    });
    </script>
```

This works on a desktop great - but on my G-Note4 and ipad mini, when I open the modal, the -15px margin-right is applied and the contents of the html expands to the right.  Does anyone have a snippet I can add to tell the above code to only work on desktop?  And on smaller devices change the margin-right to 0px; so it stops the html expanding?

Comment: Its not good idea to change margin.  Better solution is to add some class and then add your styles only in desktop media query break point in the css file.

Comment: It doesn't work by simply adding a class with css alone.  I have to modify the css when the plugin is called.  I am fighting Bootstraps modal function because it wants to add space for its scrollbar on the right, which I don't need.

Comment: So is your question really about device detection? If so, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)